# How to combine multiple XPath queries into one

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

i have a table like this

```sql
create table [Trades] (
    [Id] int not null
    ,[TradeXML] xml not null
    )
```

here's the contents of the TradeXML xml column

```xml
<Trade>
  <Arg>
    <Name>Id</Name>
    <Data>
      <DataItem DataType="8">012345678</DataItem>
    </Data>
  </Arg>
  <Arg>
    <Name>Function</Name>
    <Data>
      <DataItem DataType="8">CapFloor</DataItem>
    </Data>
  </Arg>
  <Arg>
    <Name>Curve</Name>
    <Data>
      <DataItem DataType="8">EURCurve</DataItem>
    </Data>
  </Arg>
  <Arg>
    <Name>Rates</Name>
    <Data>
      <DataItem DataType="5">2.175</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">2.169</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">2.714</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">3.394</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">3.931</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">4.477</DataItem>
      <DataItem DataType="5">4.296</DataItem>
    </Data>
  </Arg>
  <Arg>
    <Name>Index</Name>
    <Data>
      <DataItem DataType="8">EURIBOR</DataItem>
    </Data>
  </Arg>
</Trade>
```

this sql

```sql
select Node.Name.value('.', 'varchar(100)') Label
from Trades as t
cross apply t.TradeXML.nodes('//Arg/Name') Node(Name)
```

returns 5 rows:

```
Id
Function
Curve
Rates
Index
```

this sql

```sql
select Data.Name.value('.','varchar(100)') Value
from Trades as t
cross apply t.TradeXML.nodes('//Arg/Data/DataItem[1]') Data(Name)
```

returns 5 rows:

```
012345678 
CapFloor 
EURCurve 
2.175 
EURIBOR
```

and this

```sql
select Attribute.Name.query('local-name(.)') Attribute
    ,Attribute.Name.value('.', 'varchar(100)') Value
from Trades as t
cross apply t.TradeXML.nodes('//@*') Attribute(Name)
```

returns 11 rows:

```
DataType 8 
DataType 8 
DataType 8 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 5 
DataType 8
```

but what i want is the combination of this (so basically the Name, the (first) DataItem value and the value of the DataType attribute of the (first) DataItem), like this:

```
Id          012345678   8
Function    CapFloor    8
Curve       EURCurve    8
Rates       2.175       5
Index       EURIBOR     8
```

i've saved it in [rextester](http://rextester.com/BXGUK61520) to play around. i have tried to combine them myself, but didn't manage to get the correct result.
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shred the XML on `Arg` element, and select required information starting from there :

```
select 
    Node.Arg.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') Label,
    Node.Arg.value('(Data/DataItem)[1]', 'varchar(100)') DataItem,
    Node.Arg.value('(Data/DataItem)[1]/@DataType', 'varchar(100)') DataType
from Trades as t
cross apply t.TradeXML.nodes('//Arg') Node(Arg)
```

**<kbd>[`rextester demo`](http://rextester.com/AEL7195)</kbd>**